# Mouse dragging detection - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, mouse, drag

I'm making a game were the player has a spotlight and explores a few dungeons (in first person). I already made the player move but I actually have a doubt for camera rotating. I've been looking in a few forum but the issue wasn't exactly the same at mine and I'm new in Unity. The question is: How can I do to move my camera while dragging the mouse around the screen for the player to see what's happening around him?

Comment: In the standard assets package unity comes with there is a mouse look script. Use that...

Comment: Have a look at this http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseView : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float Sensitivity = 0.125f;

    Vector3 _prevMousePosition = Vector3.zero;
    float   _tilt = 0;
    float   _turn = 0;

    void Update () 
    {       
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        if( Input.GetMouseButton( 0 ) )
        {
            _tilt += -( mousePosition.y-_prevMousePosition.y ) * Sensitivity;
            _turn += ( mousePosition.x-_prevMousePosition.x ) * Sensitivity;
        }
        _prevMousePosition = mousePosition;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler( _tilt, _turn, 0 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character

> void OnUpdate() {    Turning() }
>
> ```
>  void Turning ()
> {
>     // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
>     Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
>
>     // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
>     RaycastHit floorHit;
>
>     // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
>     if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
>     {
>         // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
>         Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
>
>         // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
>         playerToMouse.y = 0f;
>
>         // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
>         Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);
>
>         // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
>         playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
>     }
> }
> ```